How to add Microsecond, Nanosecond data and how to format Ticks, tooltip in LightningChart js
I am using the LightningChart JS (trial version) in my Angular 17 application. I am trying to plot a linear-highPrecision multi-channel real time data in microseconds & nanoseconds using WebSockets. I am using a line chart and in it I am using time tick strategy.
The issue that I am facing is that when I plot microsecond data, the format of the ticks labels and tooltip shows information of X axis in milliseconds instead of showing in microseconds. It also shows the hours part in a weird format e.g. 441186.59.59.108. The same goes for the nanosecond data. It is shown in the attachment below.
My Current Result
The JSON I receive from the API is like this
[
    {
        "X": "2020-04-30T23:59:58.500001",
        "Y": 295
    },
    {
        "X": "2020-04-30T23:59:58.500002",
        "Y": 293
    },
    {
        "X": "2020-04-30T23:59:58.500003",
        "Y": 294
    },
    {
        "X": "2020-04-30T23:59:58.500004",
        "Y": 294
    }
]

I have almost 50K data points for microsecond and 10M data points for nanosecond channels.
My expected result is that when I plot microsecond data then ticks and tooltip should show data in microsecond e.g. 23:59:58.500001 and for nanosecond it should show 23:59:58.500000001.
Here is the code I am using
This code creates chart instance
  createChartInstance() {
const container = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector("#chart-container");
const lc = lightningChart({
  license: this.LIGHTNING_CHART_LICENSE_KEY,
  licenseInformation: {
    appTitle: "LightningChart JS Trial",
    company: "LightningChart Ltd."
  },
})
this.chart = lc.ChartXY({ container, theme: Themes.light, defaultAxisX: { type: 'linear-highPrecision' }, animationsEnabled: false });
this.chart.setTitle('FDR Chart');
this.chart.setAutoCursor((cursor: any) => cursor.setResultTableAutoTextStyle(true).setTickMarkerXVisible(false).setTickMarkerYAutoTextStyle(true))
this.chart.getDefaultAxisY().dispose();
const axisX = this.chart.getDefaultAxisX();
axisX.setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Time)
  .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive)
  .setDefaultInterval({ start: Date.parse('2020-04-30T23:49:58.5'), end: Date.parse('2020-04-30T23:49:59.49998'), stopAxisAfter: false })

this.chart.setMouseInteractions(true);
this.chart.setMouseInteractionRectangleFit(false)
this.chart.onSeriesBackgroundMouseDoubleClick(() => {
  this.chart.forEachAxis((axis: any) => axis.fit())
})}

This is code where I add series on the chart
addSeriesToChart(e: any, channelName: string, groupType: string) {
if (e.target.checked) {

  let axisY = this.chart.addAxisY({ iStack: this.lineSeriesCount }).setTitle(channelName).setMargins(15, 15);
  axisY.setMouseInteractions({ pan: true, zoom: false });
  const series = this.chart.addLineSeries({ axisY, dataPattern: { pattern: 'ProgressiveX' } })
    .setName(channelName);

  //Connect to the WebSocket API
  const subject = webSocket<ChartDataPoint[]>(`ws://192.168.11.145:8002/GetChartDataV3?channel=${channelName}&fileId=${this.fileId}&groupType=${groupType}`);
  subject.subscribe({
    next: (msg: any) => {
      let coordinates = msg.Coordinates
      this.websocketRunCount += 1;
      if (this.websocketRunCount == 1) {
        const startX = Date.parse(coordinates[0].X);
        const endX = Date.parse(coordinates[coordinates.length - 1].X);

        const axisX = this.chart.getDefaultAxisX();
        axisX.setInterval({ start: startX, end: endX, stopAxisAfter: false });
      }

      coordinates.forEach((point: any) => {
        series.add({ x: Date.parse(point.X), y: point.Y });
      });
    },
    error: err => console.log(err), // Log errors
    complete: () => console.log('WebSocket connection closed') // Log when the connection is closed
  });

  this.seriesList[channelName] = {
    series: series,
    axisY: axisY,
    subject: subject // Store the WebSocket subject so we can close it later
  };

  this.lineSeriesCount += 1
} else {
  this.lineSeriesCount -= 1
  this.seriesList[channelName].series.dispose();
  this.seriesList[channelName].axisY.dispose();
  this.seriesList[channelName].subject.unsubscribe(); // Close the WebSocket connection
  delete this.seriesList[channelName];
}}


Can you please edit the question to include the code that provides the JSON data to the LightningChart library, as well as any formatting functions you use

Well, you did not show us your code, so could not really pinpoint mistake in your implementation. It would be better if you include that could help me and others to answer your question in an even better way. However, you need to make sure, in order to display microseconds correctly, you are using the display axis in the correct format as mentioned in the documentation here. A sample example is also given as a reference in the link.

I have updated the question and i have added the code that i am using.
